# ReactJS: Disable mouse events in child components of parent

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have a components hierarchy like this:

```
<parent>
   <someWrapper1>
        <child>
        <child>
   <someWrapper2>
       <child>
       <child>
```

Each child component handles a bunch of mouse events on it's own where some are D3 wrappers managing `onDragStart` and `onClick` mouse events.

I am looking for a way to disable all mouse events in the `<someWrapper1/>`, `<someWrapper2/>` components, as well as in the `<child/>` components, based on the parent's component state.

One solution, would be to pass the prop of disable to the wrapper components, and to also pass those down to each child and then into
each handler to disable or enable mouse events. I want to avoid this as it will be hard to maintain.

I am looking for a nicer solution where I can disable all mouse events in all components from the parent component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to disable mouse events on specific sub-trees of your DOM. In that case, you could use the CSS `pointer-events: none;` rule to achieve this.

For example, to restrict mouse events on an element/component and it's children, you could create a style object with a `pointer-events` key and `none` value, and apply this to `<someWrapper1>` components to dynamically enable/disable mouse events on those components (and their descendants):

```
/* Your components render method */
render() {

    /* Acquire the disableEvents value from state, etc */
    const disableEvents = true;

    /* Dynamically compute style for wrapper components 
       to control mouse interactivity */
    const wrapperStyle = { 
        "pointer-events": disableEvents ? "none" : "unset" 
    };

    /* Apply dynamic styles to wrappers. When disableEvents 
       is true, mouse events will be disabled on someWrapper1
       and child descendants */
    return (<parent>
        <someWrapper1 style={wrapperStyle}>
            <child />
            <child />
        </someWrapper1>
        <someWrapper1 style={wrapperStyle}>
            <child />
            <child />
        </someWrapper1>
    </parent>)

}
```

Comment: Right. Yes, its a good approach. In my case wouldn´t work because each child is a collection of nested SVG elements, a lot. In which case the solution of invalidating events in the methods, is easier and clearer I reckon.

Comment: Ok - perhaps I misunderstood a requirement. Let me know if there's any more clarification I can offer :)

Comment: is there a way to disable pointer-events for all children in the dom hierarchy?

Comment: Yep, you could apply `pointer-events: none` to the `body` element of the document to achieve that

Comment: sweet! it was not working for me cause a deep child had pointer-events set. Thanks a lot, and yeah, this is the cleanest way for sure!